# Nesting a create view inside of a show view in Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, view, backbone.js, underscore.js

Okey, so I am totally new to backbone, and can't find the answer to my question anywhere. 
I use backbone-rails so I'm using the jst templating system. I have two models, where one of the models, say ModelA can have multiple ModelB, but ModelB can only have one ModelA (HasMany relationship).

What I want to achieve is that I have a left and a right part of the webpage, where the left page always is listing ModelA, the index view so to say, and the right part show the current selected ModelA from the left side, the show view. The right part also lists ModelB and displays a form for creating ModelB's beloning to the selected ModelA.

```
 --------------------------------------
|___ModelA list__|  ModelA - 2 details |
|_______1________|                     |
|///////2////////|     ModelB Form     |
|_______3________|                     |
|_______4________|_____ModelB List_____|
|_______5________|__________1__________|
|_______6________|__________2__________|
|_______7________|__________3__________|
|_______8________|__________4__________|
```

ModelB List shows only ModelB objects that belong to ModelA with id 2

So, I have added something like this to ModelA

```
initialize: function() {
  this.modelbs = new Appname.Collections.ModelBCollection(this.get("modelbs"));
  this.modelbs.url = this.url() + "/modelbs";
}
```

and solved the listing of ModelA in the left space by adding

> this.index()

in all the router actions (e.g. show)

So the big hundred million dollar question is, A) How to call a router action, say view in ModelB, from the show action in ModelA? and B) How to render the form for ModelB in the ModelA details section (show action) and adding the relationship to ModelA and let the ModelB view take care of the saving.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post some more code? Either way: take a look at the `render` method of model A to put in the logic of modelB's view, `initialize` modelB's view with the specific modelB instance.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is subview.

You might be interested in this: http://ricostacruz.com/backbone-patterns/#sub_views

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.